# Why $E[f(X_U)] = \lambda \int_0^{\infty} e^{- \lambda t} E[ f(X_t)]dt$ ? (Where $U$ is exponentially distributed)

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, exponential-distribution

Let $X_t$ Be a stochastic process that is independent of exponentially distributed random variable $U$ (With parameter $\lambda$). Is it true that (if so, why?)
$$
E[f(X_U)] = \lambda \int_0^{\infty} e^{- \lambda t} E[f(X_t)]dt
$$
I think the reason why I don’t get this is that I don’t really understand how to independence assumption works with stochastic processes. The $\lambda$ In the expression for sure comes from the exponential distribution but to get somewhere I think the independence has to be somehow used. I appriciate if someone can be really precise in explaining this.

Comment: The right-hand side is a random variable, while the left-hand side seems like a [deterministic] number. Either the left-hand side needs to be modified, or the right-hand side needs another expectation.

Comment: @angryavian Yes it was missing the expectation on the right. Fixed.

Comment: For every nonnegative random variable $V$ with distribution $\mu$ independent of $(X_t)$, $$E(f(X_V))=\int_0^\infty E(f(X_t))d\mu(t)$$ Is this generalization making the proof more apparent?

Comment: @Did Sure using that it follows immediately. Whats the proof of that? Or the intuition.

Comment: Simply that, for every $t$, $E(f(X_V)\mid V=t)=E(f(X_t)\mid V=t)=E(f(X_t))$ by independence of $X_t$ and $V$.

Comment: Great! So simple :-)

Comment: @Did If $(X_t)_t$ is a Markov process, then the right-hand side is the resolvent of the associated semigroup. Have you ever seen this "stochastic reperesentation" of the resolvent being used (in the framework of Markov processes)?

Comment: @saz Yes, people searching for distributions of functionals of the Brownian motion do this all the time (quite often, the distribution of $X_U$ is simpler than the distribution of every $X_t$).

Comment: @Did Hmh, yes, in fact I was wondering whether the distribution of $X_U$ is simpler than the distribution of $X_t$. I was, however, thinking about jump processes ... I have never seen this formula in this framework.

Comment: @Saz This representation pops up pretty often when dealing with control problems of diffusion processes.

Comment: @Did Do you have, by any chance, a reference to such a paper (or book)? There are plenty of works on functionals of BM and I haven't yet succeeded in finding one where the representation pops up.

Comment: @saz Not at the moment, sorry. I would look for it in anything where Marc Yor computes explicit distributions, maybe the memoir *On some exponential functionals of Brownian motion*. But really this is just the independence of $V$ and $(X_t)_t$.